# Blending videos togateher

Tags: movie-clip-editor

Absolute novice here. 
I am a professional drone pilot, who is specialising in time lapse videos. 
I have 10-15 sometimes more videos, filmed by flying same flight path at different time. 
I would like to ask how can I stitch and mainly align the clips with Blender in a smooth Time lapse video. Perhaps aligning few points from each video matching same points from the next one? 
I can not align by frames as every clip starts at different time depending on wind conditions. 
I used to use Filmora, but that is so basic and I can not align clips there. 
Thanks